# Bacterial mind control

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to remember a book in which bacteria were sentient and had formed a hive mind that the protagonist was fighting against. The bacteria could control human bodies...

Comment: Do you remember any details? When was it published or when did you read it? What were the characters like? Any major plot events? Don’t worry about spoilers, put them behind >! to hide them

Comment: Blood Music by Greg Bear fits this, except that they were nanobots, not bacteria

Comment: This is pretty tropey. You'll need to give more information to help us to positively identify it. You can improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Agree.  Any detail would help - if one of the characters hated ice tea, tell us.

Comment: This may describe the novel "The Return of Nathan Brazil", from Jack L. Chalker's "Well of Souls" series, in which a viral species invades human space.

Comment: It could also be Prey, by Michael Crichton.

Comment: The fact that this question is attracting multiple "*it could be this*" comments is precisely the reason we close questions like this as lacking focus